# Speed improvements and confusion for MapThread and Dot

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra, finite-element-method, compile

I have a question / confusion over improving the speed of `MapThread[Dot,...]` for lists of tensors. My problem involves taking two lists of tensors and then computing the list of dot products. I have found that I can speed this up by a factor of 2 or 3 by compiling `Dot` and using `Listable` to run over the list. However, it seems that once I reach rank 3 tensors, the compiled version is actually slower than the naive `MapThread[Dot,...]` implementation.

The background is that I have a list of functions together with their derivatives

$$s_\alpha,\quad \partial_i s_\alpha,\quad \partial_i \partial_j s_\alpha,$$

where $\alpha=1,\ldots,N_f$ and $i,j=1,\ldots,5$. These are lists of rank 1, 2 and 3 tensors. I then evaluate these for $N_p$ points, giving me a list of complex, machine precision tensors in packed arrays. I then need to compute various dot products, for example

$$ \partial_i \partial_j s_\alpha\,  \bar{s}_\alpha\quad\text{or}\quad \partial_i \partial_j s_\alpha\, \partial_k \partial_l \bar{s}_\alpha,$$

giving a list of length $N_p$ with rank 2 (5 x 5) or rank 4 (5 x 5 x 5 x 5) tensors.

Here is a working example where I take the dot product for a list of rank 3 and rank 1 tensors (where the compiled version is indeed quicker) and for two lists of rank 3 tensors (where the compiled version is slower). I'm running this on a 16-core machine with 256 GB of RAM, so I don't think I'm running into a memory issue. The only thing I can think of is that there is some copying involved for the compiled versions and the copying becomes the limiting factor for the higher rank tensors?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
(*number of points and functions*)
Np = 200000;
Nf = 100;

(*value of functions and second derivatives at each point*)
s = RandomComplex[{-0.1, 0.1}, {Np, Nf}];
s$deriv2 = RandomComplex[{-0.1, 0.1}, {Np, 5, 5, Nf}];

(*define compiled function for rank 3 x rank 1 dot*)
MapThreadDot31 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 3}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(*define compiled function for rank 3 x rank 3 dot*)
MapThreadDot33 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 3}, {x, _Complex, 3}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(*compute dot product for rank 3 x rank 1 tensors*)
(*compiled version is more than 10x quicker*)
MapThreadDot31[s$deriv2, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
MapThread[Dot, {s$deriv2, Conjugate[s]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*0.717989 s*)
(*10.6436 s*)

(*compute dot product for rank 3 x rank 3 tensors*)
(*compiled version is 3x slower*)
MapThreadDot33[s$deriv2, 
   ConjugateTranspose[s$deriv2, {1, 3, 4, 2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
MapThread[
   Dot, {s$deriv2, 
    ConjugateTranspose[s$deriv2, {1, 3, 4, 2}]}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*135.947 s*)
(*48.2371 s*)
```

**Update**

As a simpler example, we can compute the dot products of lists of large vectors, where I run into the same problem. Here is some sample code that computes the dot product for vectors using a number of different ways - `MapThread[Dot,..]`, mixtures of `Listable`, `Table` (from Shadowray's comment),`Parallelization`, compiling to C or WVM. Some observations:

- Listable + compiled to C + parallelize is quicker than all of the methods, until we seem to hit some size limit for the vectors, after which it becomes the slowest.
- Listable + parallelize suffers from this problem greatly. Table + parallelize does not seem to.
- Table does not seem to gain any speed up from parallelize, even for smaller vectors.
- Listable without parallelize performs the same as Table with or without parallelize.

Any ideas for recovering the speed up obtained from parallelizing the Listable method? I use vectors of greatly varying length, so it would be nice if a single method worked for all of them. Thanks for the help so far!

```
(* Listable + C + parallel *)
MapThreadDot11$listable$C = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 1}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(* Listable + WVM + parallel *)
MapThreadDot11$listable = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 1}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

(* Listable + C *)
MapThreadDot11$listable$C$1 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 1}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(* Listable + WVM *)
MapThreadDot11$listable$1 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 1}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

(* Table + C + parallel *)
MapThreadDot11$table$C = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {x, _Complex, 2}}, 
   Table[Dot[m[[i]], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m]}], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   Parallelization -> True];

(* Table + WVM + parallel *)
MapThreadDot11$table = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {x, _Complex, 2}}, 
   Table[Dot[m[[i]], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m]}], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   Parallelization -> True];

(* Table + C *)
MapThreadDot11$table$C$1 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {x, _Complex, 2}}, 
   Table[Dot[m[[i]], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m]}], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(* Table + WVM *)
MapThreadDot11$table$1 = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 2}, {x, _Complex, 2}}, 
   Table[Dot[m[[i]], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m]}], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(* Define number of points and functions *)
Np = 200000;
Nf = 500;
s = RandomComplex[{-0.1, 0.1}, {Np, Nf}];

(*Timings when we let Nf vary from 500 to 4000*)
MapThread[Dot, {s, Conjugate[s]}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 2.6s, 1000: 5.5s, 2000:  11s, 3000: 16s, 4000: 17s*)
MapThreadDot11$listable$C[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.3s, 1000: 0.7s, 2000: 1.7s, 3000: 71s, 4000: 99s*)
MapThreadDot11$listable[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.3s, 1000: 0.7s, 2000: 1.7s, 3000: 88s, 4000: 67s*)
MapThreadDot11$listable$C$1[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 1.0s, 1000: 1.7s, 2000: 3.5s, 3000:  9s, 4000:  8s*)
MapThreadDot11$listable$1[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.9s, 1000: 1.7s, 2000: 3.6s, 3000:  7s, 4000: 11s*)
MapThreadDot11$table$C[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.9s, 1000: 2.7s, 2000: 3.6s, 3000:  6s, 4000: 11s*)
MapThreadDot11$table[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.9s, 1000: 1.7s, 2000: 3.6s, 3000:  6s, 4000:  9s*)
MapThreadDot11$table$C$1[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.7s, 1000: 1.7s, 2000: 3.6s, 3000:  8s, 4000:  9s*)
MapThreadDot11$table$1[s, Conjugate[s]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*500: 0.9s, 1000: 2.9s, 2000: 4.2s, 3000: 10s, 4000: 10s*)
```

**Update 2**

There seems to be some sudden change in behaviour as `Nf` reaches 2048. This causes a sudden change in the timings, as set out below. For comparison, I've used the MapThreadDot from FEM - this is on par performance wise with the other methods suggested. While `MapThreadDot11$listable$C` is faster for `Nf<2048`, it suddenly becomes slower than the other functions for `Nf>=2048`. Note that this seems to be independent of `Np`, the number of points - changing `Np` to a much smaller or larger number does not change this conclusion (I have set this to 100,000 in the below example so it should run with much less RAM). Could it be that it suddenly uses a different BLAS function once the size of the vectors that we are taking the dot product of reaches 2048? It is definitely linked to parallelizing the calculation over many cores. I see this problem on the 16 core machine I've been using, but not on my 2 core laptop...

```
(* Listable + C + parallel *)
MapThreadDot11$listable$C = 
  Compile[{{m, _Complex, 1}, {x, _Complex, 1}}, Dot[m, x], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C"];

(* Define number of points *)
Np = 100000;

(* Timings for different values of Nf *)

Nf = 2046;
s = RandomComplex[{-0.1, 0.1}, {Np, Nf}];

NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot[s,Conjugate[s]]; //AbsoluteTiming
MapThreadDot11$listable$C[s, Conjugate[s]]; //AbsoluteTiming
(* Nf: 2046; FEM: 1.3s; Listable: 0.5s *)
(* Nf: 2047; FEM: 1.3s; Listable: 0.5s *)
(* Nf: 2048; FEM: 1.3s; Listable: 1.0s *)
(* Nf: 2049; FEM: 1.3s; Listable: 1.3s *)
(* Nf: 2050; FEM: 1.3s; Listable: 1.9s *)
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd assume this issue is the memory cost of passing those huge tensors to C

Comment: On my low-RAM machine (16 GB), `MapThreadDot33 ` is still faster; however, a lot of swapping is going, so that does not mean much...

Comment: Try this:  `MapThreadDot33 = Compile[{{m, _Complex, 4}, {x, _Complex, 4}}, 
  Table[Dot[m[[i]], x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[m]}]];`

Comment: So it seems that removing the `Parallelization -> True` removes all difference. Compiling to WVM instead of C seems to make no difference, so it seems the performance difference is due to copying the large tensors to the many parallel kernels (16 in this case, and the problem seems to get even worse on the 36 core machines). In addition, on my laptop there is little to no difference (I would guess as it only has two cores). For the rank 1 x rank 3 tensor calculation, the parallelized compiled function is still much faster. Any ideas for recovering some of this speed?

Comment: How does the `MapThreadDot33` function from my previous comment perform on your system? Note that it is not listable and rely on the `Table` function.

Comment: I've added an update with the timings for your method compared with Listable / compiling to C / Parallelize, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Dot` is implemented through BLAS and already parallelized.  There is also [``NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=MapThreadDot) to consider (but the vectors/matrices have to all be the same size).

Comment: I was using `NDSolve`FEM`MapThreadDot` before, then realised I needed to take dot products of tensors of different ranks, so moved away from it. I may just have to use the non-parallelized version and accept that the smaller vectors will be a little slower (though it is sad parallelize can't be used to speed up the larger vector calculations...).

Comment: "it is sad parallelize can't be used": If `Dot` already takes full advantage of your machine's parallel capacity, then it will computing the larger calculations as fast as possible. (You might check that hypothesis on your machine.)  Also I believe that the rank in BLAS's dot is limited to 2. I'm not sure exactly what *M* does for rank ≥ 3. It seems to be parallelized.

Comment: It seems like this might be some sort of memory copy problem more than anything. I've added a final update showing what happens when `Nf` changes from 2047 to 2048, causing the fastest method to suddenly become the slowest...

Comment: I have a relatively strong machine with 64G RAM and a high-end Intel processor. I don't see your timings at all. For instance, your first code-block contains 4 timings and on my machine they are: 0.6937s, 5.858s, 9.375s and 12.521s. This is also true for the other timings. I cannot confirm the vast jumps in runtime, so I guess we can assume it *has* something to do with memory or cpu.

Comment: On a 16-core machine with 256 GB RAM (2 x 8 core Intel processors from a few years ago), the timings are 0.372s, 6.55s, 49.2s, 24.5s. This indicates that having more cores does indeed help with the smaller calculation, but is a hindrance with the larger calculation. I assume that your faster core clock means that even in the larger case, the code with an explicit `Parallelization -> True` is still slightly faster that the `MapThread[Dot,...]` (but nowhere near the factor of 20 speed-up that I see for the smaller calculation). Fewer cores = less of a penalty for the larger calculation.